# Does Ubuntu 14.04 support SCTP by default

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am developing an application that will make use of some of the sctp APIs like sctp_bindx, sctp_connectx etc.

My Linux kernel version is 3.13.0-49-generic .

If I try to compile my code , I get the below error

> fatal error: netinet/sctp.h: no such file or directory.

If I install lksctp-tools package then my code got compiled.

Can I use the APIs without installing any libsctp library ? Since I read that SCTP is supported by the kenal version > 2.1

Answer (score 1):

All functions require *some* library. It just happens that glibc is automatically used whenever you use gcc.

SCTP-specific functions are not included in glibc itself, so you need to install and use the sctp library. The fact that kernel supports SCTP is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I installed libsctp and its working fine for me.

Comment: I have one more concern here, libsctp comes under which license ?

Comment: You can find this information in /usr/share/doc/libsctp-dev/copyright or /usr/include/netinet/sctp.h